# Only one value from checkbox being sent in PHP mail

Tags: php, magento

I am using a script that has a foreach loop and this shows the right amount of checkboxes depending on what is set in the admin area of Magento.

The problem that I am facing is that there may be multiple checkboxes however only the checkbox that is selected nearest the top is the value that is sent with the form. I need all the checkbox values that have been selected to be sent.

This is what I have in my mail script to get the checkboxes values `$check = $_POST['check'];`

And this is the code below that uses the foreach to show the right amount of checkboxes.

```
 <?php
    $SKU = "1282670_01";
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$SKU);
    if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){  
        $childs = $product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();  
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($childs as $child) { ?>
    <?php $colour_name =  $child->getAttributeText('real_colour'); ?>
    <li class="notranslate focused" id="fo143li2">
    <fieldset>
    <div>
    <span>

    <img width="35" height="35" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $child->getSwatch() ?>">
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-top:-10px;" onchange="handleInput(this);" tabindex="5" value="<?php echo $colour_name ?>" class="field checkbox" name="check" id="<?php echo $colour_name ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo $colour_name ?>" class="choice"></label>
```

Comment: Wonderful, you delete one question. Almost use my answer the right way in a reposted question. Now other people have to tell you the same thing I did. You are funny.

Answer (score 2):

All your checkboxes have the same name, so only one will appear in your `$_POST` array. Change the code to use unique names, or use an array form i.e. `name="check[]"`

Comment: I have changed the name to `check[]` and added `$check = array(); into the mail but in the email I just get `Array` and no data?

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowed one input to submit its value for a name (in the case of radio buttons, it uses whichever is "on"), however you can turn that key/value pair into an array by changing the name to `check[]`. Each `check[]` will be combined into an array and submitted as `name => ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']`

Similarly, you could use keys instead of pushing to the end of the array, like
`name="check[<?php echo $colour_name ?>]" value="true"` and PHP would show it as `array('red' => 'true', 'blue' => 'true')`.